# Не работает ClientWidth

Tags: javascript

Высоту окна (браузера) выводит правильно, а ширину выводит всего экрана а не окна (браузера). При этом имеется боковой scroll, должен вывести ширину без scroll.

В чем может быть проблема? Использую данный код:

```
alert( document.documentElement.clientHeight );
alert( document.documentElement.clientWidth );
```

Comment: Неправда, выводит ширину окна, я проверил

Comment: Возможно у тебя работает, но у меня сайт на HTML 5 и может поэтому не работает?

Comment: Ваш код рабочий. Выводит размер рабочей области браузера без скроллбара.

Comment: Но скроллбар есть и он прокручивает страницу

Comment: может вам надо брать `clientWidth` не у `document`, а у `body`?

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось дописать к `<script>` defer.